# Holder continuous analytic function

Tags: cv.complex-variables

Assume that $0<\alpha<1/2$ and $f$ is analytic in the unit disk $D$ with $|f(z)-f(w)|\le M|z-w|^\alpha$. Can we state that in general $$\int_D |f'(z)|^2 dx dy <\infty?$$

Comment: Is there a reason to believe or hope that it is true?

Comment: There is an example of a function which satisfies the Holder condition on the boundary circle (which I suspect implies the Holder condition on the interior as well) but has Taylor coefficients $O(n^{-1})$, so does not lie in Dirichlet space

Comment: @Yemon choi: Of course if, the function in Holder in the boundary, then it is Holder continuous inside. Probably you right!